# Logical Notations for Mathematical Statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I'm studying discrete mathematics and I'm faced with a problem of converting a few descriptive mathematical statements into logical notation. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

> a) Any divisor of an integer is less than or equal to itself.
>
> b) Any integer greater than $1$ has at least one prime divisor.

I'm supposed to solve it using the "usual arithmetic operators: $+, -, *, /, =, \ne, <, >,\le$, and $\ge$".

I have attempted part (a):

$$ (n\in \mathbb{Z} \wedge x \mid n)\to (x \le n) $$

Here $x$ is any arbitrary number that divides an integer. Is it right?

Comment: Are you allowed to use quantifiers? If so, this is more like a first-order case than a propositional one. (And then you would need to quantify over your attempt in order to say "any integer")

Comment: As per above comment, you need *quantifiers*. In general, a statement like "Any integer greater than 1 has at least one prime divisor" must be previously rewritten as : "**For any** integer greater than 1 **there exists at least one** prime divisor". In this way, it is evident the need for two quantifiers, one *universal* ($\forall$ : fo any) and one *existential* ($\exists$ : there exists at least one). We can then improve it as : "**For any** integer $n$, **there exists at least one** integer $p$ such that, if $n$ is greater than 1, then $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$". 1/2

Comment: Now the symbolic form is straightforward :  : $\forall n \exists p(n > 1 \rightarrow  (prime(p) \land p|n))$. 2/2

Comment: Most of the divisors of $-6$ (e.g. $-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,6$) are strictly greater than $-6$

Answer (score 1):

> I have attempted part a.
>
> $( n \in \mathbb Z \wedge x \mid n) \implies (x \leq n)$
>
> Here x is any arbitrary number that divides an integer. Is it right?

Mostly.  You need quantifiers for "any".

$$\forall x\; \forall n :\Bigl( x,n\in \mathbb Z\wedge (x\mid n)\implies(x\leq n)\Bigr)$$

Sometimes written as : $\forall x \in \mathbb Z, \forall n \in \mathbb Z: (x\mid n)\implies (x\leq n)$

Likewise, for part **b** you'll need to identify that there exists a prime, *somewhere* in the statement.
 $$\exists m: m\in\mathbb P$$

> > b Any integer greater than 1  has at least one prime divisor.

Can you do it now?

Comment: what is the quantifier for any? thanks for the previous help.

never mind, i got it. Thanks.

Comment: @user3813179 "any", "all", "each", "every", *et cetera* are expressions of the **universal quantifier**: $\forall$